# Populate a dynamic select menu with records from database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Im trying to populate a select menu based on the user selection in a previous menu. I'm only using one model in which i store all the records that the user is filtering through. The problem that i have is to only get unique records and not all records based on the previous choice.

**schools_controller**

```
    class SchoolsController < ApplicationController
  def region
    @user = current_user
    @regions = School.select(:region).uniq.order(:region)
  end

  def municipalities
    @municipalities = School.where(:region => params[:region]).uniq



  end
end
```

**Model**

```
    # == Schema Information
#
# Table name: schools
#
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  region       :string(255)
#  municipality :string(255)
#  school       :string(255)
#  created_at   :datetime         not null
#  updated_at   :datetime         not null
#

class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :region, :municipality, :school
  has_many :users
end
```

**regions.html.erb**

```
 <%= form_tag 'municipalities' do %>
<p><%= select_tag(:region, options_from_collection_for_select(@regions, 'region', 'region')) %>
</p><p>
<%= submit_tag 'Nästa', :class=> 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

**municipalities.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag 'schools' do %>
<p><%= select_tag(:municipalities, options_from_collection_for_select(@municipalities ,:municipality ,:municipality )) %>
</p><p>
<%= submit_tag 'Nästa', :class=> 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Ryan's railscast on dynamic select menus http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised. Or take a look at the dynamic_form gem.

Both do the trick, the dyanic_form gem takes a lot of the coding out of the way as you'd expect, and uses more coffescript rather than javascript